# Unable to reflect the value to q-table column

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Even though 'if-condition' executes with the console logs, after running if part, else part is getting executed and returning 'NA' values for all the q-table's verbrauch column. I don't understand the issue here

```
renderSummeHtml = (summe: IntranetPortalSumme, summedTitle: string) => `
  ${summe.isSummed ? `<i>${summedTitle}</i><br>` : ""}
  ${summe.sums
    .map((s) => `${numberFormatter(s.scalar)} ${s.unit}`)
    .join("<br>")}
  ${summe.hasUnknowns ? "<br>(Nicht summierbarer Bestandteil)" : ""}`;`
```

```
    label: t("locationView.intranetView.consumption"),
    renderHtml: (row: ArbeitsplatzRow) => {
      console.log(row.apLo, row.apLo?.summe);
      const scalarValue = row.apLo?.summe?.sums[0]?.scalar;
      if (scalarValue !== undefined) {
        const sumValue = renderSummeHtml(row.apLo!.summe!, "Verbrauchssumme:");
        console.log(sumValue);
        return sumValue;
      } else {
        console.log("No Data for row");
        return "NA";
      }
    },
    showForGroupChildren: true,
    sortable: false,
  },


log for sumValue:  30 g / Einheit
```